# How to categorize calendar events in Android?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I intend to create an Android Application which manages Calendar Events. Unfortunately, I don't see a way in which I can present the user a way to add events for a given category, that the user might create.

[Link to CalendarContracts.Events in official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html)

The **CalendarProcider.Events** **table** doesn't seem to have any field, where I can store the **category** the event belongs to. Should I create a new calendar, linked to the same account, for each new category that I'd like to create? Is that the only way, if not the recommended one?

Comment: I prefer using the Google Calendar API
because it's something that most users nowadays are familiar with which helps with the learning curve for your app. Here is a link to the front page of the Google Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ if you are interested in looking into that instead of using the Android built in Calendar functionality. The documentation is super helpful with getting you setup.

Comment: @BrendanOswego I don't think even Google Calendar API has the capability to categorize events as such i.e. group them. Moreover, I am trying to make an interface that would work with whatever calendar the user chooses.

Answer (score 1):

http://android.calengoo.com/pagedoc/pageinstallation/pageeventcolors/pageeventcolors.html

This link here argues that, perhaps different calendars should be created to represent the different categories.

> Calendars in Google Calendar are like categories for your events. Just create additional calendars to categorize your events. E.g. you could create calendars named "Work", "Home", "Family", "Sports", "TV" and so on. By saving an event into a calendar the event will be displayed with the color of the calendar. An additional advantage when assigning colors to your events this way is that you can easily hide certain calendars/categories with a single tap by using the calendar selection bar.

I feel the reasoning is perfectly sane, and would provide the same functionality, unless there is another legit way to create categories within the same calendar.